# Javascript onclick menu button show sidebar, onmouseleave hide sidebar

Tags: javascript

I have a sidebar which is hidden by default and a menu button which trigger the sidebar. So far, everything is working but what I want is, when I click on the menu, the sidebar gets opened and on mouse leave, the sidebar gets closed.

I have checked other solutions and tried to implement it in my code but its not working.

Here are my html and js

```
//html
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- sidebar content -->

    <!-- Menu button -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
            <span class="hamb-top"></span>
            <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
            <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


//js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
          overlay = $('.overlay'),
         isClosed = false;

        trigger.click(function () {
          hamburger_cross();  
        });

        function hamburger_cross() {

          if (isClosed == true) {          
            overlay.hide();
            trigger.removeClass('is-open');
            trigger.addClass('is-closed');
            isClosed = false;
          } else {   
            overlay.show();
            trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
            trigger.addClass('is-open');
            isClosed = true;
          }
      }

      $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
      });  
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Put the relevant code only rather than dumping whole code here..

Comment: sorry for that, I have just edited the post and removed the extra code.

Comment: @KingFaw what if the user doesn't have a mouse? how do they "mouse leave"? How does this work on a tablet? How does this work if the user's only using a keyboard?

Comment: if the user is using a phone, the latter can still press the menu button as when the sidebar opens, its menu button moves to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the menu on mouseleave you may write:

```
$('.navbar').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
   trigger.click(); // simulate the action you now do to close the menu
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
      isClosed = false;

  trigger.click(function () {
    hamburger_cross();
  });
  $('.navbar').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    trigger.click();
  })

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 220px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 220px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -220px;
}
 .sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
  color: #999;
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
  background-color: #52b6ec;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;

}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}

.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, .8);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav sidebar-nav">
            <div class="gap"><br><br><br></div>
            <li>
                <a href="services.php">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#777;">Works <span
                        class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
            <span class="hamb-top"></span>
            <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
            <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out gaetanoM.